# Overwrite parent functions in child function.php WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using a child theme.

Here's the parent function

```
function aaron_customize_css() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
     if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) {
        ?>
        .main-navigation{top:32px;}
        @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
            .main-navigation{top:46px;}
        }
        @media screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
            .main-navigation{top:0px;}
        }    
    <?php
     }
    echo '.site-title{color:#' . get_header_textcolor() . ';} ';
    $header_image = get_header_image();
    if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) {
    ?>
        .site-header {
        background: <?php esc_attr_e( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgcolor', '#fafafa') ) ?> url(<?php header_image(); ?>) <?php esc_attr_e( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgrepeat', 'no-repeat') ); ?> <?php esc_attr_e( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgpos', 'center top') ); ?>;
        background-size: <?php esc_attr_e( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgsize', 'cover') ); ?>;
        }
    <?php
    /* No image has been chosen, check for background color: */
    }else{
        if( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgcolor') ){
            echo '.site-header { background:' . esc_attr( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgcolor', '#fafafa') ) . ';}';
            echo '#action:hover, #action:focus{text-shadow:none;}';
        }
    }
    //Call to Action text color
    if( get_theme_mod( 'aaron_action_color' ) <> ' ') {
        echo '#action, #action a{ color:' . esc_attr( get_theme_mod('aaron_action_color', '#000000') ) . ';}';
    }
    echo '</style>' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css');
```

Here's the child function which is already edited.

```
function aaron_customize_css_child() {
  echo "<!-- test i am in child theme   -->     ";
  echo '<style type="text/css">';
  if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) {
    ?>
    .main-navigation{top:32px;}
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
      .main-navigation{top:46px;}
    }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 600px ) {
      .main-navigation{top:0px;}
    }
    <?php
    }
    echo '.site-title{color:#' . get_header_textcolor() . ';} ';
    $header_image = get_header_image();
    if (! empty( $header_image)) {
      ?>
      .site-header {
        background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size:    cover;
        -o-background-size:      cover;
        background-size:         cover;
        }
    <?php
    /* No image has been chosen, check for background color: */
    }else{
        if( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgcolor') ){
          echo '.site-header { background:' . esc_attr( get_theme_mod('aaron_header_bgcolor', '#fafafa') ) . ';}';
          echo '#action:hover, #action:focus{text-shadow:none;}';
        }
    }
    echo '</style>' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css_child');
```

I'm trying to overwrite the parent function in function.php. I followed the instructions from http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-modify-the-parent-theme-behavior-within-the-child-theme--wp-31006. But it's not working. I even looked into several questions on stackoverflow but it didn't have what I was looking for. I did check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes and it said that I can replace the parent function in child functions.php by declaring

```
if(!function_exists( 'aaron_customize_css')) {
  function aaron_customize_css() {}
}
```

I even tried many other methods but I couldn't get it to work. Help?

Comment: The functions don't have the same name. Did you want to call the parent function from the child in *addition* to new functionality specific to the child? Or did you want a complete override?

Comment: complete override. sorry about the child function, I forgot to remove the "_child" from the child function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "remove" the parent theme function with [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action). This function removes a function which has been attached to a specified action hook, and is often used to replace functions with a substitute:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css');
```

And then add your own function in place of it:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css_child');
```

So, in all, you'll have something like the following in your child theme:

```
function aaron_customize_css_child() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css');
    // function contents
}
add_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css_child', 100);
```

Comment: Tried that but it's not working....:(
should it be add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_theme_features', 10 );
 
function remove_parent_theme_features() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css');
add_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css_child');
}
but should the last sentence be add_action('wp_head', 'aaron_customize_css'); without the word "_child"? I just want to override the parent function or something like that...

Comment: I can't read any of that...but is your child theme function at least outputting  `test i am in child theme`?

Comment: I just edited my example to nest the `remove_action` within the child function

Comment: Something else is going on if your function isn't even running. Regardless of whether or not the parent function is running, your child function should be...I hate to ask, but is the child theme activated through the admin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78425/discussion-between-kristina-bressler-and-rnevius).

Comment: One more thing, How do one overwrite `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/highlights.php';`? I tried to fix it by creating second files and stuff and adding "2" to the end of highlights, making it 'highlights2.php' but it's not working...

Comment: This is the error I got
Warning: require(/home/thewhisperwithin/public_html/wp-content/themes/aaron/inc/highlights2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/thewhisperwithin/public_html/wp-content/themes/aaron-child/functions.php on line 42

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/thewhisperwithin/public_html/wp-content/themes/aaron/inc/highlights2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/thewhisperwithin/public_html/wp-content/themes/aaron-child/functions.php on line 42